# Question in Lagrangian formalism

Tags: lagrangian-formalism

In lagrangian mechanics, 
where $L=T-U$
and the lagrangian formulation is $ \frac{d}{dt}\big( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}}\big)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial {q_i}}=F_i$,
where $F$ is the non-conservative force.

My question is if I want to find out the above equation for a given problem then the $q_i$ should be written for every term in which the system is expressed.
Like if I want to write the equation for a pendulum then the $q_i$ will be the angle displacement.

So for example in a double pendulum there will be two angles $\phi ,\theta $ for the respective rods than the equation in lagrangian formalism will be
$$\frac{dL}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}}+\frac{\partial L}{ \partial \dot{\theta}})+\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}=0$$
is this correct?

Comment: Even though you are right, The E-L equations for both the coordinates are individually $0$ too, you are just doing $0+0$, also $F_i$ in your equations is a _non_ conservative force

Comment: Every post on this site is a question so there's no need to remind the readers that the question is a question in the title. Please see our [FAQ on writing good titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you get a separate Euler-Lagrange equation for each individual degree of freedom, i.e. a system of simultaneous equations. So in your example,

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} &= 0, \,\mathrm{and} \\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} &= 0
\end{align}

Comment: but why are these $q_i $is in the equation @lemon

Comment: @Boris I don't understand what you're asking...

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}\big( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}}\big)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial {q_i}}=F_i$ for what are these 'i' in this equation @lemon

Comment: $q_1=\theta,\,q_2=\phi$. So set $i=1$ and you get the first equation I give above, and set $i=2$ and you get the second. They are *not* to be interpreted as Einstein summation...